# Why is my my custom edit page for my custom admin panel not working?

Tags: magento2.3, admin, grid, custom

fellow Magento developers. Ive been working on this new exercise including a whole admin panel and all that. i was working on the edit and ran into an issue that produces these 2 errors in my log

> main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Smart\Banner\Controller\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\Interceptor" {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\App\Request\InvalidRequestException(code: 0): Invalid request received at D:\Projects\mag6\vendor\magento\framework\App\Request\HttpMethodValidator.php:69)"} []
> main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http://127.0.0.1:8090/index.php/admin_1svdad/smart_banner/banner/edit/id/36/key/4dab352e3f21454a6619c5f072d8ef3cf757ec535eb6815a4459c8f7166c8664/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"LOCKED_RECORD_INFO_BLOCK_635c37e4d9084fb1bbdb04eaa956f5ea95c792a9"}} []

And here is all code relating to this functionality and ill try to be brief and keep the code only limited to whats relevant

This file is located in

> Smart/Banner/view/adminhtml/ui_component/smart_banner_listing.xml

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">
            smart_banner_listing.smart_banner_listing_data_source
        </item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">
            smart_banner_listing.smart_banner_listing_data_source
        </item>
    </item>

    <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">smartcoloumn</item>
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Banner</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>

<dataSource name="smart_banner_listing_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">
            Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider
        </argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">smart_banner_listing_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
</dataSource>

<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
    <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
    <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>
    <filters name="listing_filters"/>
    <massaction name="listing_massaction">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <action name="delete">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="smart_banner/Banner/massDelete"/>
                    <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete Post</item>
                        <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you want to delete
                            selected items?
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
    </massaction>
    <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    <exportButton name="export_button"/>
</listingToolbar>

 <columns name="smartcoloumn">
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>

     <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Smart\Banner\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ServiceActions">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </actionsColumn>
        </columns>
    </listing>
```

AS you see my file ServiceActions is called and here is its code:

This file is located in

> Smart/Banner/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/ServiceActions.php

```
<?php

namespace Smart\Banner\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class ServiceActions extends Column
{

protected $urlBuilder;

public function __construct(
    ContextInterface $context,
    UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
    UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
    array $components = [],
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
}

public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
{
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
            $item[$this->getData('name')]['edit'] = [
                'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                    'smart_banner/banner/edit',
                    ['id' => $item['id'],]
                ),
                'label' => __('Edit'),
                'hidden' => false,
            ];
        }
    }

    return $dataSource;
}
```

}

and this file calls the layout and the code for that is as follows:

This file is located in:

> Smart/Banner/view/adminhtml/layout/smart_banner_banner_edit.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <update handle="editor"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Smart\Banner\Block\Adminhtml\Edit" name="service_edit" template="Smart_Banner::edit.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

and the controller for the edit is standard:

This file is located in:

> Smart/Banner/Controller/Adminhtml/Banner/Edit.php

```
    <?php
    namespace Smart\Banner\Controller\Adminhtml\Banner;
    
    use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
    use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
    use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class Edit extends Action implements HttpPostActionInterface
{

protected $_coreRegistry;
protected $pageLayoutBuilder;


protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Smart_Banner::banner_edit');
}


public function __construct(
    Context  $context,
    Registry $registry
)
{
    $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
    parent::__construct($context);
}


public function execute()
{
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Smart\Banner\Model\Banner');
    if ($id) {
        $model->load($id);
        if (!$model->getId()) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('This Banner no longer exists.'));
            $this->_redirect('smart/banner/*');
            return;
        }
    }
    $layout = $this->_view->loadLayout();
    $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();

    $this->_coreRegistry->register('smart_banner', $model);

    $title = $this->_view->getPage()->getConfig()->getTitle();
    $title->prepend(__("Banner"));

    $breadcrumb = $id ? __('Edit Banner') : __('New Banner');
    $this->_addBreadcrumb($breadcrumb, $breadcrumb);

    $this->_view->renderLayout();
}
```

}

And the block file that the layout calls is this:

This file is located in

> Smart/Banner/Block/Adminhtml/Edit.php

```
<?php

namespace Smart\Banner\Block\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class Edit extends Container
{

    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Registry $registry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context  $context,
        Registry $registry,
        array    $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Init class
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_objectId = 'id';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_banner';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'ShopForBuild_SmartBanner';

        parent::_construct();

        $this->buttonList->update('save', 'label', __('Save Banner'));
        $this->buttonList->update('delete', 'label', __('Delete Banner'));

        $this->buttonList->add(
            'save_and_continue',
            [
                'label' => __('Save and Continue Edit'),
                'class' => 'save',
                'data_attribute' => [
                    'mage-init' => ['button' => ['event' => 'saveAndContinueEdit', 'target' => '#edit_form']],
                ]
            ],
            10
        );
    }
}
```

the layout file also calls a template file and the code for that is also very standard

This file is located in

> Smart/Banner/view/adminhtml/templates/edit.phtml

```
<?php

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container;
?>
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo $block->getFormInitScripts() ?>
<?php if ($block->getButtonsHtml('toolbar')): ?>
    <div class="page-form-actions" <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
    echo $block->getUiId('content-header') ?>><?php echo $block->getButtonsHtml('toolbar') ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php echo $block->getFormHtml() ?>
<?php if ($block->hasFooterButtons()): ?>
    <div class="content-footer">
        <p class="form-buttons"><?php echo $block->getButtonsHtml('footer') ?></p>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'mage/backend/form',
        'mage/backend/validation'
    ], function ($) {
        $('#edit_form').form()
            .validation({
                validationUrl: '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getValidationUrl() ?>',
                highlight: function (element) {
                    var detailsElement = $(element).closest('details');
                    if (detailsElement.length && detailsElement.is('.details')) {
                        var summaryElement = detailsElement.find('summary');
                        if (summaryElement.length && summaryElement.attr('aria-expanded') === "false") {
                            summaryElement.trigger('click');
                        }
                    }
                    $(element).trigger('highlight.validate');
                }
            });
    });
</script>
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo $block->getFormScripts() ?>
```

But after all that I seem to get the error, I mentioned above and I get this on screen
[image]

But I don't understand what am I missing? is there something I'm not seeing? can someone help me get this edit page to work or at least show? I would greatly appreciate any help you guys can offer. Thanks in advance and Merry Christmas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all I needed to do was go to the controller for the edit located in:

> Smart/Banner/Controller/Adminhtml/Banner/Edit.php

and change the class it implements from POST to GET

```
class Edit extends Action implements HttpGetActionInterface
```